# C++ Ternary Operator with Equality Statement

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

While debugging someone else's code, I ran into an expression of the following form:

```
auto result = value == bool_value? result_if_bool_value: result_if_not_bool_value
```

I am familiar with ternary operators, but I am confused by the double equality operator in the above statement.

Specifically, what is the equivalent of the above command written with if-else statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional operator has lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `==`. Hence the line is parsed as:

```
auto result = (value == bool_value ) ? result_if_bool_value: result_if_not_bool_value
```

It is the usual

```
( condition ) ? expr_true : expr_false
```

In general the conditional operator is *not* equivalent to an `if`, but you get the same result with

```
T result;  // auto does not work here !!
if ( value == bool_value ) result = result_if_bool_value;
else result = result_if_not_bool_value;
```

or if you want to keep `auto`:

```
auto result = result_if_not_bool_value;
if (value == bool_value) result = result_if_bool_value;
```

Though, depending on the actual types involved this might do something entirely different than the original (`result_if_not_bool_value` is here evaluated independent of the condition and there is one initialization and potentially one assignment compared to only initialization. I could swap `result_if_not_bool_value` with `result_if_bool_value`, but then the condition would need to be negated which in all generality might result in different result. Though this is all just being super defensive, when the types involved behave "normal", it is mainly a matter of style.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
auto result = value == bool_value? result_if_bool_value : result_if_not_bool_value;
```

is grouped as

```
auto result = ((value == bool_value) ? result_if_bool_value : result_if_not_bool_value);
```

It's not possible for me to trivially reformulate this into the equivalent `if` statement due to your use of `auto`. The type of the ternary conditional expression is the common type of `result_if_bool_value` and `result_if_not_bool_value`.

If the types of `result_if_bool_value` and `result_if_not_bool_value` were `T` say, and `T` has an assignment operator, then the equivalent `if` block would be

```
T result;
if (value == bool_value){
    result = result_if_bool_value;
} else {
    result = result_if_not_bool_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully equivalent code would be (C++17 onward)

```
auto maker = [&](bool condition)
{
     if ( condition )
         return r1;
     else
         return r2;
};

auto result = maker(value == bool_value);
```

Although a good argument could be made that it is harder to understand lambdas and RVO than it is to understand the conditional operator .

Answer (score 0):

If `value == bool_value` evaluates to `true`, `result` is assigned `result_if_bool_value` else `result` is initialized `result_if_not_bool_value`.

Comment: `result` is initialized, not assigned